Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'?
Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. The tags are correct.
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Bose-QuietComfort-Cancelling-Headphones-Bluetooth/dp/B0CCZ26B5V/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2491RYA872DT3&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.nt7VYtXp5pWj7xfzTrxzsfBi7xDLEcL_Ph-ke9myd8-dXCeIaAXuKVBFQXNPD2c0_SjLQkXBe_aMyr648OQPVUI6rX2eQnp823zAKljvkC4NhQ6756Bw4s2Gc8AG4bEJx9ndltFcrjCeK-tgaVlbK77agZb5oykKzvYDhkCm2ycTiIMfn5-yPGbRgzYWX4Juzb1SrfBu2lj_kz5dXKyD1-P2Hm8hNX3F_VrpCGqGRKo.cGaDMSRHm-DXr5z4IFZW5juUZ8mbIgzEYcHxnG3kPlA&dib_tag=se&keywords=headphones&qid=1718911530&sprefix=head%2Caps%2C452&sr=8-3&th=1'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(),"html.parser")

title = soup2.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
price = soup2.find(class_='aok-offscreen').get_text()

price = price.strip()[1:]
title = title.strip()

print(title)
print(price)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 20
     16 soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
     18 soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(),"html.parser")
---> 20 title = soup2.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
     22 price_element = soup.find(class_='aok-offscreen')
     23 if price_element:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

From the documentation on get_text I can't figure it out. If I remove print(price) and run it a few times it works.

It means it couldn't find the ID you're looking for.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

It works when soup2.find(id='productTitle') can find the title with such an id. Check if this part soup2.find(id='productTitle') is not None before using get_text() method

That is: before posting, carefully check what result you actually get, from each step of the code, to see what part is actually going wrong. The code title = soup2.find(id='productTitle').get_text() does three things: it tries to .find something in the soup, tries to .get_text from that, and tries to assign the found text to title. Which of those parts do you think is going wrong? (Did you try to check?)

Why are you parsing the HTML twice? You should be able to use soup1 for everything.

check the returned html, you probably are getting the captcha page

You need to add an if, in case the element was not available or there was other potential issues, or put a timer (time.sleep()), or some other retry (try-except) mechanism so that it would wait or retry after a second or two:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def _scrape(url):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    te = soup.find(id='productTitle')
    title = te.get_text(strip=True) if te else "Title not found."
    pe = soup.find(class_='aok-offscreen')
    price = pe.get_text(strip=True) if pe else "Price not found."

    return title, price


URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Bose-QuietComfort-Cancelling-Headphones-Bluetooth/dp/B0CCZ26B5V/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2491RYA872DT3&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.nt7VYtXp5pWj7xfzTrxzsfBi7xDLEcL_Ph-ke9myd8-dXCeIaAXuKVBFQXNPD2c0_SjLQkXBe_aMyr648OQPVUI6rX2eQnp823zAKljvkC4NhQ6756Bw4s2Gc8AG4bEJx9ndltFcrjCeK-tgaVlbK77agZb5oykKzvYDhkCm2ycTiIMfn5-yPGbRgzYWX4Juzb1SrfBu2lj_kz5dXKyD1-P2Hm8hNX3F_VrpCGqGRKo.cGaDMSRHm-DXr5z4IFZW5juUZ8mbIgzEYcHxnG3kPlA&dib_tag=se&keywords=headphones&qid=1718911530&sprefix=head%2Caps%2C452&sr=8-3&th=1'
print(_scrape(URL))


Prints
('Bose QuietComfort Wireless Noise Cancelling Headphones, Bluetooth Over Ear Headphones with Up To 24 Hours of Battery Life, Black', '$349.00')



Comments:

or put a timer Would that actually help, given they are using requests and not a real browser? – John Gordon

A delay or a retry (try-except-retry) mechanism might address some potential issues such as network latency, temporary server unavailability, or slow response times, which might happen from time to time, regardless of whether a browser is used or not.

Note that some websites have higher levels and layers of security firewalls and they would suppress some of these requests without providing any clear messages.



or put a timer Would that actually help, given they are using requests and not a real browser?
